# AssertConfigurationIsValid() when using nested ConstructUsing, without ignoring private setters

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-9

With the following example (LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationNested>()
            .ConstructUsing((source, context) => new DestinationNested(source.InnerValue));

        cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationOuter>()
            .ForMember(x => x.OuterValue, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.OuterValue))
            .ConstructUsing((source, context) =>
            {
                return new DestinationOuter(source.OuterValue, context.Mapper.Map<DestinationNested>(source));
            });

    });

    var src = new Source { OuterValue = 999, InnerValue = 111 };

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var mapped = mapper.Map<DestinationOuter>(src);

    mapped.Dump();

    mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}

public class Source
{
    public int OuterValue { get; set; }
    public int InnerValue { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationOuter
{
    public int OuterValue { get; private set; }
    public DestinationNested destinationNested { get; private set; }

    public DestinationOuter(int outerValue, DestinationNested destinationNested)
    {
        this.OuterValue = outerValue;
        this.destinationNested = destinationNested;
    }
}

public class DestinationNested
{
    public int NestedValue { get; private set; }

    public DestinationNested(int nestedValue)
    {
        this.NestedValue = nestedValue;
    }
}
```

AssertConfigurationIsValid() currently throws an exception regarding the properties as I'm using ContructUsing.

In practice it does map correctly, but I'd like AssertConfigurationIsValid as part of my test suite to look for regressions (without needing to do manual tests of the mapper).

I'd like reassurance that all my properties are mapped from the source to the destination **via** the contructor. I wish to use a contructor as it's my Domain tier and the contructor enforces the mandatory items.

I don't wish to ignore all private setters via the IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter() feature, as I might be ignoring something which I haven't actually set.

Ideally I also don't want to need to do manual Ignore() on each of the properties which appear in the constructor as that leaves a gap for code drift.

I've tried various combinations in Automapper but no luck so far.

I suppose it's a static analysis challenge; I wish to know that my contructor covers all properties in the Destination. And I wish to know that the contructor is being passed everything from the source.

I realise that Automapper isn't doing very much automatic at this point, is there a nice way to lean on automapper for this testing or is this instead a static  analysis problem?

Comment: You need `ConvertUsing`, not `ConstructUsing`.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu that's certainly got me a step closer! It didn't _feel_ like it was a type conversion issue, but it is working! Am I right in thinking the reason this is working is that it's a global Source -> Destination conversion and it doesn't care about the properties any more?

If so, I wonder why ContructUsing doesn't have the same behaviour? I suppose because you could have a constructor and a property set afterwards? 

I suppose I will need some static analysis as well to ensure that my constructors cover all of my properties?

Comment: Yes :) Complex `ConstructUsing` is a code smell. Look into [constructor mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html).

Comment: :-) Agreed I think my automapping isn't very automated anymore! Thanks for the tip, I tried ForCtorParam, but couldn't get nested types working with it so ended up down the route of ContructUsing, unless there's an alternative I've missed (I've been digging into the intergration tests to learn more techniques :-) )

Comment: Research flattening and unflattening.

Comment: Hi @LucianBargaoanu I think I've found a solution, I'd be interested in hearing what you think. Btw, thanks for the tips, it's fantastic to get first-hand advice from an author of AutoMapper (now seeing your name throughout the git commits!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try{
    var mapperCfg = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationOuter>().ForCtorParam("destinationNested", o => o.MapFrom(s => new DestinationNested(s.InnerValue)));
    });
    mapperCfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    var mapper = mapperCfg.CreateMapper();

    var src = new Source { OuterValue = 999, InnerValue = 111 };
    mapper.Map<DestinationOuter>(src).Dump();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.ToString().Dump();
    }
}
public class Source
{
    public int OuterValue { get; set; }
    public int InnerValue { get; set; }
}
public class DestinationOuter
{
    public int OuterValue { get; }
    public DestinationNested DestinationNested { get; }

    public DestinationOuter(int outerValue, DestinationNested destinationNested)
    {
        this.OuterValue = outerValue;
        this.DestinationNested = destinationNested;
    }
}
public class DestinationNested
{
    public int NestedValue { get; private set; }

    public DestinationNested(int nestedValue)
    {
        this.NestedValue = nestedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks Lucian, that's a clean answer. It reduces the code needed and probably rightfully pushes the constructor's responsibility of setting up it's properties upon itself, whilst still allowing the top level to be validated. The only downside would be perhaps constructing multi-nested classes, but that's outside of this question.

Comment: Details aside, you have to work _with_ AM as much as possible. The less custom configuration you have, the cleaner and easier to understand the end result is. But of course the people reading the code must understand the patterns AM implements.

Answer (score 0):

After reading lots of docs, stepping through the integration tests with the debugger and a few days of good'ol experimentation, this is the best I have:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationNested>()
            .ForCtorParam("nestedValue", x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InnerValue))
            .ForMember(x => x.NestedValue, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InnerValue));

        cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationOuter>()
            .ForPath(x => x.destinationNested.NestedValue, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InnerValue))
            .ForCtorParam("destinationNested", x => x.MapFrom(y => y));
    });
```

I'm pretty happy with it; it's getting rid of the ContructUsing() smell which in my broader codebase was constructing the nested objects. And it's warning me if my destination object is not populated. Ideally, the constructor param string would be type safe, but I understand why it cannot (perhaps this is something for a fun Roslyn code analyser project for another day :-) )

The secret sauce (hot of the press) was the `x => x.MapFrom(y => y)` coupled with the `.ForPath(x => x.destinationNested.NestedValue, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InnerValue))` it seemed to give AutoMapper enough hints that the destinationNested was related to InnerValue and that the contructor param was renamed to "destinationNested". The magic came in that rather than using the context to contruct the nested object the innocent looking `x.MapFrom(y => y)` seemed to let it use the property mapping instead*.

*That's my layman's explanation, I haven't yet followed enough of the AutoMapper source code to understand the relationship between property mapping and constructor mapping truely. Reading through some GitHub tickets, I thought they were separate concepts.

I also haven't seen `x.MapFrom(y => y)` mentioned in the docs, so I'd be interested in learning more about it.